# Is there a simple way to replace with placeholders in Excel?

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have a formula like this:

```
=IF(OR($A1="xyz",$B1="abc",$C5="dmz"),1,0)
```

I'd like to replace each cell address with a static address that explicitly states the worksheet, i.e.

```
=IF(OR(Sheet1!$A$1="xyz",Sheet1!$B$1="abc",Sheet1!$C$5="dmz"),1,0)
```

I have this:

```
Public Function absoluteFormula(sheetname As String, ByVal formula As String) As String

Dim re As New RegExp
Dim matches As MatchCollection
Dim mtch As Match
Dim absoluteAddress As String


'get all addresses in formula
re.pattern = "[$][A-Za-z]+[0-9]+"
re.Global = True

Set matches = re.Execute(formula)

'replace each address with its static version
For Each mtch In matches
    absoluteAddress = sheetname & "!" & getAbsoluteAddress(re, mtch.value)
    formula = Replace(formula, mtch.value, absoluteAddress)
Next

absoluteFormula = formula

End Function


'makes row static, e.g. "$AU1" -> "$AU$1"
Private Function getAbsoluteAddress(re As RegExp, address As String)

Dim matches As MatchCollection
Dim alphaColumn As String


re.pattern = "[A-Za-z]+"

Set matches = re.Execute(address)
alphaColumn = matches(0).value
getAbsoluteAddress = Replace(address, alphaColumn, alphaColumn & "$")


End Function
```

This seems like a lot of code to accomplish what is basically (pseudocode):

```
find all instances of "[$][alpha]+"
replace with sheetname & "!" & instance & "$"
```

Is there a simpler way to perform this substitution?

Comment: What about NamedRanges?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I don't understand your comment.  I'm not trying to make the formula shorter, I'm trying to perform a replace operation to change it from relative to absolute.

Comment: Sorry let me explain... let's say in your formula you have a named range which refers to a cell address. How do you plan to append/Change sheetname there?

Comment: Example `=IF(OR($A1="xyz",Sid="abc",$C5="dmz"),1,0)` Where `Sid` refers to `=Sheet2!$A$1`

Comment: @SiddharthRout, we can assume that a prior validation step will guarantee only explicit cell addresses.

Comment: You could look at the `Precedents` property of the `Range` object. That would avoid the need for RegExp. Never used it myself so not sure if there any pitfalls.

Comment: @ChipsLetten: You are right. I was already working on that. :D

Comment: @ChipsLetten, that would certainly give me a collection of all the cells used in the formula, but then wouldn't I have to reconstruct the formula with all those cells?  Or is there a way to use `.Precedents` to show which absolute precedent corresponds with which relative reference in the formula?

Comment: ++ Good question... Made me experiment a lot :D

Comment: @sigil - you are correct, you would still need work out whether the precedent was used with relative or absolute references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Not completely tested** but would something like this help? Select a single cell which has a formula and run `Sample`. I have not done any error handling. I am assuming that the `ActiveCell` *WILL* have a formula. I am also going with what you said in the above comment that your formula will not have *Named Ranges*

```
Dim sformula As String
Dim sh As String

Sub Sample()
    Dim cell As Range, c As Range

    '~~> This is what you want to append
    sh = "Sheet1!"

    '~~> Store the formula in a variable
    sformula = ActiveCell.Formula

    Debug.Print sformula

    '~~> Get the precedents
    Set cell = ActiveCell.Precedents

    '~~> Loop though them
    For Each c In cell
        ReplaceAddress c.Address                                            '~~> $A$1
        ReplaceAddress c.Address(RowAbsolute:=False)                        '~~> $A1
        ReplaceAddress c.Address(ColumnAbsolute:=False)                     '~~> A$1
        ReplaceAddress c.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) '~~> A1
    Next

    Debug.Print sformula
End Sub

Function ReplaceAddress(s As String) As String
    Dim pos As Long

    pos = InStr(1, sformula, s)

    Do While pos > 0
        If pos = 1 Then
            sformula = sh & sformula
        ElseIf pos > 1 Then
            '~~> Various checks for "!","$" and ":"
            If Mid(sformula, pos - 1, 1) <> "!" And Mid(sformula, pos - 1, 1) <> "$" And _
            Mid(sformula, pos - 1, 1) <> ":" And Mid(sformula, pos - 2, 1) <> ":" Then
                sformula = Left(sformula, pos - 1) & sh & Mid(sformula, pos)
            End If
        End If
        '~~> Find next occurance
        pos = InStr(pos + 1, sformula, s)
    Loop
    ReplaceAddress = sformula
End Function
```

**Various tests**

Before:

```
=IF(OR($A1="xyz",$B1="abc",$C5="dmz"),1,0)
```

After:

```
=IF(OR(Sheet1!$A1="xyz",Sheet1!$B1="abc",Sheet1!$C5="dmz"),1,0)
```

---

Before:

```
=VLOOKUP(K4,N10:Q18,1,0)
```

After:

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!K4,Sheet1!N10:Q18,1,0)
```

---

A slightly more complex test

Before:

```
=IF(G4>MAX($D$4:$D$8),"N/A",INDEX($B$4:$B$8,INDEX(MATCH(G4,$C$4:$C$8,1),0,0),0))
```

After:

```
=IF(Sheet1!G4>MAX(Sheet1!$D$4:$D$8),"N/A",INDEX(Sheet1!$B$4:$B$8,INDEX(MATCH(Sheet1!G4,Sheet1!$C$4:$C$8,1),0,0),0))
```

**Followup from comments**

Use this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim cell As Range, c As Range

    '~~> This is what you want to append
    sh = "Sheet1!"

    '~~> Store the formula in a variable
    sformula = ActiveCell.Formula

    Debug.Print sformula

    '~~> Get the precedents
    Set cell = ActiveCell.Precedents

    '~~> Loop though them
    For Each c In cell
        ReplaceAddress c.Address                                            '~~> $A$1
        ReplaceAddress c.Address(RowAbsolute:=False)                        '~~> $A1
        ReplaceAddress c.Address(ColumnAbsolute:=False)                     '~~> A$1
        ReplaceAddress c.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) '~~> A1

        sformula = Replace(sformula, c.Address(RowAbsolute:=False), c.Address)
        sformula = Replace(sformula, c.Address(ColumnAbsolute:=False), c.Address)
        sformula = Replace(sformula, c.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False), c.Address)
    Next

    Do While InStr(1, sformula, "$$")
        sformula = Replace(sformula, "$$", "$")
    Loop

    Debug.Print sformula
End Sub

Function ReplaceAddress(s As String) As String
    Dim pos As Long

    pos = InStr(1, sformula, s)

    Do While pos > 0
        If pos = 1 Then
            sformula = sh & sformula
        ElseIf pos > 1 Then
            '~~> Various checks for "!","$" and ":"
            On Error Resume Next
            If Mid(sformula, pos - 1, 1) <> "!" And Mid(sformula, pos - 1, 1) <> "$" And _
            Mid(sformula, pos - 1, 1) <> ":" And Mid(sformula, pos - 2, 1) <> ":" Then
                sformula = Left(sformula, pos - 1) & sh & Mid(sformula, pos)
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
        '~~> Find next occurance
        pos = InStr(pos + 1, sformula, s)
    Loop
    ReplaceAddress = sformula
End Function
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to convert the relative address to an absolute address (see the `$A1`->`Sheet1!$A$1` example in my OP).  It was probably confusing for me to use "static" and "absolute" interchangeably, sorry about that.  I see where you're going with this, though, and now I understand what you mean about `.Precedents`.

Comment: That is also easy :) Remove the first check and change `sformula = Left(sformula, pos - 1) & sh & Mid(sformula, pos)` to convert your static to absolute.

Comment: Is this what you are trying? Changing  `=IF(G4>MAX(D$4:$D8),"N/A",INDEX(B$4:$B8,INDEX(MATCH(G4,C$4:C$8,1),0,0),0))` to 
`=IF(Sheet1!$G$4>MAX(Sheet1!$D$4:$D$8),"N/A",INDEX(Sheet1!$B$4:$$B$8,INDEX(MATCH(Sheet1!$G$4,Sheet1!$C$4:$C$8,1),0,0),0))`

Comment: Yes, that's the desired result, although there shouldn't be that second "$" on "$$B$8".

Comment: That works for the examples that we discussed.  It fails if a precedent is at the beginning of the formula (e.g. `=A2&B5`).  But it's fine for the data set that I'm working with.

Comment: I thought i took care of that.. let me check

Comment: I have updated the function. Now check it please. You may have to refresh the page

Comment: @SiddharthRout, your long answers are worth the length. Patience is a priceless thing :)